# Repeat a function for every row in a database and display it

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm looking for two things:

- a. how to run the procedure below for every row in a database
- b. how to provide a graphical display of the information

  ```
              a = Session("Price")
              b = Session("Price")
              c = Session("Price")

          ((If Session("GH") = "Yes" Then
              a = a * (1 + Session("GH2"))
              z = z + 1
          End If
          If Session("DH") = "Yes" Then
              b = b + (1 + Session("DH2"))
              z = z + 1
          End If
          If Session("CD") = "Yes" Then
              c = c * (1 + Session("CD2"))
              z = z + 1
          End If

          End If) 
          PriceFinal = (a + b + c) / z)
  ```

There are multiple vendors that offer a specific product searched for by the customer. The price is subject to change. I want to display all of the vendors that offer this product with the adjusted price (hence the procedure above). I am using ASP.NET and was warned about using `GridView`. If someone could suggest an alternative that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an SQL stored procedure (or function) that calculates PriceFinal, and create a query that returns that long with the other columns you want to display.